# how to use selenium with fitnesse

Tags: selenium-webdriver, fitnesse, selenium-fitnesse-bridge

I am creating a small test. In Code behind I have two classes. Pages, LoginPage. 
The first part is running. I dont know how to integrate with second part. Currently I am able to open the browser. Also I am trying to use the Page obect model pattern .

```
Fitnesse code
    !|import|
    |TestFramework|

    !|script|Pages|
    |Goto||https://gmail.com|
    |LoginPage|CheckRequiredElementsPresent|Pass|


Fixtures 

public class Pages 
{
   string url;
   private LoginPage loginPage;

   public static void Goto(string url)
   {
       Browser.Goto(url);
   }
}


public class LoginPage 
{

    static string PageTitle;

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "TextUsername")]
    private static IWebElement username;

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "TextPassword")]
    private static  IWebElement password;

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "_ButtonLogin")]
    private static IWebElement submit;

    public string IsAtLoginPage()
    {
        return "";
    }
    public string CheckRequiredElementsPresent()
    {            

        if (username != null && password != null && submit != null)
        {
            return "Pass";
        }
        return "Fail";
    }

}
```

}

Comment: you didn't add any reference for your second class in fitnesse fixture..

Comment: I just modified the code. but its not able to find the method CheckrequiredElementsPresent

Comment: check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like below:

### Fitnesse Code

```
    !|import|
    |TestFramework|

    !|script|Pages|
    |Goto||https://gmail.com|
    |check Required Element|Pass|
```

You need to call your second class from your Pages class, please see the code changes & fitnesse fixture changes that I've made.

### Fixtures

```
public class Pages 
{
   string url;
   private LoginPage loginPage;

   public static void Goto(string url)
   {
       Browser.Goto(url);
   }

   // This is what you need to do to refer method of second class. 
   // This method will be called after Goto method in sequence.

   public boolean checkRequiredElement(){
      return loginPage.CheckRequiredElementsPresent()
   }

}
```

Comment: You have kind of mixed Java and C# here though.